# Create Draggable Markers and save them in the Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I wanna know if in Gmaps4Rails we can create Draggable Markers on it, exactly as we do using Geocoder, etc.

Also, can I display an generic html form listing datas from the Markers inside the Infowindow?

Thanks to all!

Comment: There are no restrictions in gmaps4rails: it provides what google maps provides. So it's a yes to your questions.

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer, ask a more detailed question with code

Comment: Can you please, share some light on? I'm trying to use the 'Javascript goodies' scripts, but it does'nt seems to work, or I'm placing the code in a wrong place (I'm using this post as a [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209597/gmaps4rails-drop-marker-to-new-position)) Can you show me a detailed version of how to do the draggable marker? It would be very appreciated. Thanks. (:

Comment: Which version of the gem do you use?

Comment: Btw check examples here: http://apneadiving.github.io/ it answers your infowindow question

Comment: Here I have gmaps4rails 2.1.0, with Rails 4.0.3 and Ruby 2.0.0. Yes, I have checked the page, and it's closely to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This answers your questions:

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: { }, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  var json_data = [
    {
      id:  1,
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0,
      infowindow: "<div style='color:red;'>Foo</div>" //this html is properly disaplayed
    }
  ];

  //create draggable markers (pass google maps options aas a second arg)
  var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_data, { draggable: true});

  //add markers to original json
  _.each(json_data, function(json, index){
    json.marker = markers[index];
  });

  //add dragend event to markers, triggered when you drop them
  _.each(json_data, function(json){
    google.maps.event.addListener(json.marker.getServiceObject(), "dragend", function(event) {
      var lat = event.latLng.lat();
      var lng = event.latLng.lng();
      console.log('Marker with id: ' + json.id + ' dropped hat lat: ' + lat + ' and lng: ' + lng)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: More or less. I mean, it was only when adding a new Position on the map. When it was listing, it was to work normally as in your example. Btw, in this version how do I get the `markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);` to work along this example? Thanks for the help man! Here a <3 to you